# Ionic 3 custom selector for ion-option

Tags: javascript, angular, ionic-framework, ionic3

I have an ion-select with dynamic ion-option. My task is to disable the save button of ion-select when more than 5 result are selected. I found ionSelect event which calls controller method each time when an checkbox is clicked in ion-select.

My code:

HTML:

```
<ion-select [(ngModel)]="users" multiple="true">
      <ion-option value="{{t.userId}}" *ngFor="let t of possibleUsers" (ionSelect)="onUserSelect()">{{t.userName}}</ion-option>
</ion-select>
```

TS:

```
public onUserSelect(value) {
 console.log(value);
}
```

How I see value param in onUserSelect method is the selected checkbox value and before it is checked or unchecked. So without a selector I cannot tell on which checkbox was clicked with javascript.

I cannot add any selector to ion-option, I already tried:

```
[custom-data]="t.userId", class="my-class", id="customId-{{t.userId}}", data-custom="customId-{{t.userId}}"
```

But none of them are added to ion-option.

Any idea how to add unique selector to ion-option or how to send checkbox state in ionSelect event?

Comment: If my understanding is correct you meant to call the onEmployeeSelect in (ionSelect) instead of onUserSelect() ?

Comment: Thanks, but the problem is not this. I will correct in the question

Comment: could you elaborate then?

Comment: Yeah, I noticed. But you mentioned that "the problem is not this".

Answer (score 0):

Hope this is you are expecting to do

```js
  onUserSelect(value) {
    console.log(value);
  }
```

```html
<ion-select [(ngModel)]="users" multiple="true">
      <ion-option value="{{t.userId}}" *ngFor="let t of possibleUsers" (ionSelect)="onUserSelect(t.userId)">{{t.userName}}</ion-option>
</ion-select>
<!-- if this is your save button -->
<button ion-button [disabled]="users.length > 5">Save</button>
```

Comment: Unfortunately not, how I see onUserSelect(t.userId) an onUserSelect($event) have the same result. And the ion-select save/ok button which close the select needs to be disabled not the page save button.

Comment: for that we need to write our own controller for ion-select. Because Ion-select works on top of dialog (action, popover and alert). So writing custom dialog with the options to add the inputs will be the best solutions

Comment: yeah, I also thought on this solution just was curious if I could do it in other way or with javascript somehow

Comment: yeah! it would be great at least if they provided any events for ion-option selection